# Automatically add FacesMessage when a certain business exception is thrown in JSF 2

Tags: jsf, exception, message

I would like to know if the following is possible with JSF2.
When my business classes or DAO classes are throwing a certain exception (e.g. a custom exception called BusinessException) a FacesMessage gets added to the current page with a standard message string for this exception class. The business classes and the managed beans are in two different projects. Only the managed beans have access to the business classes.

Comment: What problem do you have? Just catch the exception from the managed bean and add the message there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a snippet like this in your managed bean:

```
try
{
   ... do your staff here ...

} catch (YourBusinessException ex)
{
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Your custom message"));
}
```

This is a general approach and it will work if your business method throws a YourBusinessException instead of catching it.

Comment: Thanks for your post. This approach is quite abvious and I already use it like this but I am looking for a more general way where I do not need all these try catch things in all my methods where I need business logic. I thought about something like this: My business class throws a custom RuntimeException and without any catches the message panel gets updates with a specfic message. So maybe each time my own BusinessRuntimeException is thrown the following message will be printed: An error occured. Please contact your administrator

Comment: Or you can just wrap all the exceptions in a custom exception with a String property you can use to arbitrary set the message. You can also override getMessage() to return super.getMessage() if the property is null or the property itself if it's different.

Comment: Of course but thats not what I am looking for. I do not want to try and catch all business calls. It should work like a RuntimeException and this should be catched on the fly without writing try {}catch..

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a parent bean from which every single managed bean could extend from. There, implement an access point for each of your service calls.

That solution depends of course in how many service operations you have and if they're reused by diferent managed beans. Apart from that, keep in mind that you could need to handle the exceptions on the parent in other way that could not be just adding a message. That question **depends a lot** in your current implementation and application type.

Just think about it:

```
public abstract class ParentBean{

    Service service;

    public void performOperationAtService(){
        try{
            service.operation();
        }catch(YourBusinessException ex){
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("An error occured. Please contact your administrator"));
        }
    }

}

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ConcreteBean extends ParentBean{

    public void someAction(){
        //Do some stuff
        super.performOperationAtService();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok I see that is not a really answerable question. Your solution may work in some situations but for me this would not fullfill my needs. But nevertheless thanks for your opinion.

Comment: As you see vague questions carry on vague answers. Next time try to be a bit more specific to obtain what you want.